# Load & view movies on a hard drive in Netflix-like UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a self-taught programmer and would like anyone to point out anything that is not the standard or professional way to do things. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

I would love to post a lot of my code or perhaps make a youtube video explaining certain portions for feedback. Let me know in the comments what you think.

The specific code I would like feedback for is how I take the movies I have found and add them to the listView. This takes the most time and is roughly 1 movie every second.

[image: program image]

To start you hit Load.

```
    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if (bgwPopulateMyMovies.IsBusy == false)
        // {
        //     bgwPopulateMyMovies.RunWorkerAsync();
        // }
        Thread movieThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(populateVideosGrid));
        movieThread.Start();
        labelTotalMyVideos.Text = "My Videos: " + dgwMyVideos.Rows.Count.ToString();

    }
```

I originally had the code in a backgroundWorker, but it ran substantially slower.

This triggers my populateVideosGrid() method. Which will get the movies from a dataGrid on my other tab that is populated with movies.

```
    private void populateVideosGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgwMyVideos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i >= dgwMyVideos.Rows.Count)
                return;

            string moviePath = "";
            string Year = "";
            string Season = "";
            string Episode = "";
            try
            {
                moviePath = dgwMyVideos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                Year = dgwMyVideos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                Season = dgwMyVideos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                Episode = dgwMyVideos.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                if (moviePath != "")
                    addToMyVideos(moviePath, Year, Season, Episode);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Where I loop through the dataGrid and call addToMyVideos method.

```
    private void addToMyVideos(string Name, string Year, string Season, string Episode)
    {

        this.labelTotalMyVideos.Invoke(new UIUpdaterDelegate(() =>
        {
            this.labelTotalMyVideos.Text = "My Videos: " + MoviesManager.MyMoviesCount.ToString();
        }));

        TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie aMovie = new TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie();
        Name = MovieCleaner.justMovieName(Name, Year);
        aMovie = MyMovie.loadTMDbLib(Name);
        if (MyMovie.lastImage != null)
        {
            //MyMoviesCollection.Add(aMovie);
            if (aMovie != null)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(MySettings + "//cache//"))
                    AddOneEntryToMyVideos(aMovie, MyMovie.lastImage);
            }
            else
                return;
        }
    }
```

This is where I believe the majority of the bottle neck is as I have to use the TMDbLib API to pull movie information. Every. Single. Time. This calls the AddOneEntryToMyVideos method.

```
        private void AddOneEntryToMyVideos(MyMovie aMovie)
    {
        //locate image
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(aMovie.Image);
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                Image bigImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    this.imageListMyMoviesLarge.Images.Add(bigImage);
                }));
            }
        }//failed to locate movie, use a image unavail
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create("http://blogs.ncs-nj.org/k4stemlab/files/2013/04/image-unavailable.jpg");
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                Image bigImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    this.imageListMyMoviesLarge.Images.Add(bigImage);
                }));
            }
        }

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.ImageIndex = listView2.Items.Count;
        item.Name = aMovie.number.ToString();

        this.listView2.Invoke(new UIUpdaterDelegate(() =>
        {
            this.listView2.Items.Add(item);
        }));

        this.labelMoviesInView.Invoke(new UIUpdaterDelegate(() =>
        {
            this.labelMoviesInView.Text = "Movies in view: " + listView2.Items.Count.ToString();
        }));

        //set focus on added item
        if (checkBoxSetMovieFocus.Checked == true)
            this.listView2.Invoke(new UIUpdaterDelegate(() =>
            {
                this.listView2.Items[listView2.Items.Count - 1].Focused = true;
                //this.listView2.TopItem = listView2.Items[listView2.Items.Count - 1];
            }));
    }
```

The code above is going to download the image from a stream and add it to a ImageList/ListView object. Last it updates a few labels in the form.

Comment: Welcome to CR! The whole code is in the form's code-behind? I'd suggest you [edit] the post to simply include the whole class instead of disparate snippets, for full context (leave the notes about your concerns though) - you have a potentially *beautiful* CR post here, which will receive answers from which you'll probably learn tons! Enjoy the ride :-)

Comment: The code base is quite large. I use multi classes to do different things and my Form1.cs(Main form) is 1691 lines long. :( Still post it? If I can link YouTube videos here I would rather record myself explaining what everything does. Some other parts of my code do entirelly different things. I didn't want to overload the post haha.

Comment: Maximum character count is 65K; I'd post the code-behind, and link to github for the other contextual code - you have that on github right? Off-site links are fine for additional context, but the reviewable content must be embedded in the post. Don't worry about making a long post - as long as it's [nicely formatted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help), properly broken down and narrated, it's all good.

Comment: Installing github

Comment: https://github.com/czzplnm/Movie-Management-V55/tree/master/Movie%20Management

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: why a Windows Forms application? IMHO it's outdated technology, and you should look at [WPF and beyond](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn973012.aspx).

---

The first bit of code you post already shows a bad practice: `button13_Click` is obviously linked to a button called `button13`, and that name is utterly meaningless. You say that this is what is triggered when you hit Load -- so why then not call it a `LoadButton`?

---

Please read up on the [capitalization conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx): methods -- `populateVideosGrid()` for instance -- should be PascalCase.

But this method name also exposes how deeply your application logic is tied to your UI, and that's a bad thing. If you had used WPF, you could have [implemented MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484.aspx) but this kind of separation is much harder to do in WF.

---

Even though `populateVideosGrid()` is only twenty-odd lines long, there's much more wrong with it. You use `try... catch` but ignore the exception: that's bad. But I wonder why there's even the possibility of an exception happening?

Why do you use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`? You should also move the logic inside the try to a separate method which accepts a `Row` as the parameter.

`if (moviePath != "")` is odd. Why not use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`? Also, why even bother assigning `Year`, `Season` and `Episode` if `moviePath` doesn't contain a value?

`Year`, `Season` and `Episode` should be camelCase.

---

Why do you need to specify the whole namespace in `TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie aMovie`? And why is your variable named `aMovie` -- why not just name it `movie`?

`justMovieName` is a [bad method name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx), since it lacks a verb or verb phrase.

Parameters should be camelcase: `addToMyVideos(string Name, string Year, string Season, string Episode)`.

---

You say:

> This is where I believe the majority of the bottle neck is as I have
>   to use the TMDbLib API to pull movie information. Every. Single. Time.

Aren't there batch methods available? Can't you cache data for movies in a local db or an XML file so you only need to look up movies that aren't stored in that db or file?

Also: are you seriously retrieving "image-unavailable.jpg" ***every time***? Why? Do you expect it to change form one second to the other? Why not get it once and store it on your HD and retrieve it from there?

---

The main problem I see is that you haven't separated your concerns. Read up on [n-tier architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/662107/Understand-Tier-Architecture-in-Csharp) and realize that you shouldn't tie your UI to your other logic.

Consider this approach:

- All your UI needs is a list of "movies"
- By "movies" I mean classes with a number of properties:

  - their location on disc,
  - the *local* path to an image,
  - the title etc.
- That information is stored locally,

  - and if it isn't you need to retrieve it from TMDb and then **store it locally**.

Work with smaller blocks of logic, each designed for a specific function. Start from there, and then try to improve on your logic. For instance:

- perhaps the exception that occurs in `AddOneEntryToMyVideos` might be solved later on,
- so you'll need to re-query TMDb at a later time -- but not each time the screen refreshes,
- which means you need to store a date at which you last queried TMDb
- and only query it again once a certain amount of time has passed.

Also look into async operations and parallelism, in order to execute multiple queries to TMDb at the same time.

Comment: +1 but windows forms is definitely easier to get going in than WPF which is a pretty compelling reason for its continued use.

Comment: Very good points all around but I think you ask "why" too much, as in "Why are you doing it this way?"  In the opening sentence the OP clearly states he is a self taught programmer.  The reason why he is doing things incorrectly is because he's never been shown the right way.  But that's why he posted here in the first place!

Comment: @RickDavin Yes, you're right. On the other hand, it isn't a bad habit to reflect on your own code. I get the feeling a lot of this is copy-pasted from examples, which isn't necessarily bad as long as you understand what you are doing, hence the odd mix of naming styles (the correct `response` vs the odd `aMovie`, for instance).

Comment: How do I respond to this answer in a nice format? The n-th architecture looks great!

Comment: @Illuminati the WinForms way of decoupling application logic from UI is the Model-View-Presenter pattern - look it up! Feel free to post your refactored code in a new question whenever you're ready :-)